# how do you get data from Clickhouse in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, clickhouse

as a developer, I have book table in Postgres with bookId, title, description. and have book_tracking have bookId, viewCount.

Now I want to get viewCount from clickhouse, then mix it with title, description then provide it in a materialized table in postgres. How can I do that?

example:

| POSTGRES TABLE | CLICKHOUSE TABLE | EXPECT POSTGRES TABLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **books** | **books_tracking** | **mv_books** |
| bookId | bookId | bookId |
| title | view_count | title |
| description |  | description |
|  |  | view_count (from clickhouse) |

the first solution is: create Foreign Data Wrappers (FDW) (look like not stable, hard to setup)

second solution is: create a table, update it manually by cronjob. truncate it then fill it with data from clickhouse every 5 minute (I'm using this way)
is there any better solution?

Comment: I would check the foreign data wrapper, by far the easiest solution. But if you're under the impression that this one isn't stable, then you need something different. Your application could also merge the two data sources into a single report

Comment: What FDW did you try to set up?  What about it seemed unstable?

Comment: aw, I try to work with FDW @jjanes but the pgModeller is just recreate and break my model everytime I generate it. But I can't live without Pgmodeller :(